# Look up correct value from Google Sheet using an ID - Avoid multiple "else if" blocks - Build array

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a monthly report that lists vendor IDs and items they delivered. Each vendor delivers only two types of items and each line on the report represents a single delivery.

I wrote a script that reads the report and builds an array with the following structure: VendorID1, Item1Count, Item2Count, VendorID2, Item1Count, Item2Count, VendorID3, Item1Count, Item2Count and so on.

I then need to fill out a table within Google Sheets using the data in the array. However, the table contains Vendor Names, but not Vendor IDs so it makes it trickier to enter data correctly.

Basically I need to get a Vendor Name from the column in Google Sheets, associate it with the correct Vendor ID in the array and enter Item1 and Item2 counts in the columns next to the Vendor Name.

Here's the script I wrote, which seems to work, but I need to write out about 40 lines of "else if" statements (one for each vendor) and I was wondering if there is a better way of handling this task.

```
// item_counts is an array containing vendor IDs and item counts. 
// Every 3rd index is a vendor ID. 
// Start iterating through the array using For loop, skipping every 3rd index.
for (i=0; i<item_counts.length; i=i+3) {

// Manually assign Vendor Names to a variable based on Vendor ID. 
// "vendor_names" match values in the Google Sheets Vendor column.
  if (item_counts[i] == “vendor_id1”) { var vendorName = “vendor_name1”; }
  else if (item_counts[i] == “vendor_id2”) { var vendorName = “vendor_name2”; }
  else if (item_counts[i] == “vendor_id3”) { var vendorName = “vendor_name3”; }
……
  else if (item_counts[i] == “vendor_id40”) { var vendorName = “vendor_name40”; }
// If there is no match (Vendor ID is in the array, but isn't needed), 
// skip iteration to avoid incorrectly associating a Vendor ID to a 
// Vendor Name previously assigned to vendorName variable
  else {continue};

// vendor_name_col is an array of Vendor Names obtained from Google Sheets table 
// using getRange().getValues(). Iterate through the list 
// of Vendor Names in the table. If a match is found to vendorName, 
// enter data from the array.
  for (j=0; j<vendor_name_col.length; j++) { 

    if (vendor_name_col[j][0] == vendorName) {

    // this section will eventually be replaced with code that 
    // enters item1 and item2 counts in the columns next to Vendor 
    // Names in Google Sheets table using getRange.setValue().
    // Displays VendorID/Vendor Name, followed by item counts.
      Logger.log(“Counts for "+ item_counts[i]+"/"+vendor_name_col[j][0]);
      Logger.log("Item1: "+item_counts[i+1]);
      Logger.log("Item2: "+item_counts[i+2]);
    }
  }
}
```

Modified code after suggestions from Sandy Good and tehhowch:

```
var objMapVendorToName,vendorID,vendorName;
var multi_id_vendor1_item1_count = 0;
var multi_id_vendor1_item2_count = 0;
var multi_id_vendors = ['multi_id_vendor1', 'multi_id_vendor2', 'multi_id_vendor3'];

// Associate a vendor ID with a vendor name
objMapVendorToName = {
  'vendor_id1':'vendor_name1',
  'vendor_id2':'vendor_name2',
  'vendor_id3':'vendor_name3'
}

for (i=0; i<item_counts.length; i++) {

  vendorID = item_counts[i][0];
  vendorName = objMapVendorToName[vendorID];

  // vendor_name_col is an array of Vendor Names obtained from Google Sheets table 
  // using getRange().getValues(). Iterate through the list 
  // of Vendor Names in the table. If a match is found to vendorName, 
  // enter data from the array.

  for (j=0; j<vendor_name_col.length; j++) {

    // Vendor Name does NOT have multiple Vendor IDs associated with it
    if (vendor_name_col[j][0] == vendorName && multi_id_vendors.indexOf(vendor_name_col[j][0]) === -1) {

      // Displays VendorID/Vendor Name, followed by item counts for verification

      Logger.log(“Counts for "+ item_counts[i]+"/"+vendor_name_col[j][0]);

      // Final code will enter this data in the corresponding spreadsheet cells
      Logger.log("Item1: "+item_counts[i][1]); 
      Logger.log("Item2: "+item_counts[i][2]);
    }
    // This else if seems clunky, but does appear to work. Vendor Name
    // DOES have multiple Vendor IDs associated with it

    else if (vendor_name_col[j][0] == vendorName && vendorName == 'multi_id_vendor1') {

      multi_id_vendor1_item1_count += item_counts[i][1];
      multi_id_vendor1_item2_count += item_counts[i][2]; 
    }
  }
}

// After all iterations are complete, enter 
// multi_id_vendor1_item1_count and multi_id_vendor1_item2_count in the spreadsheet
 Logger.log("Item1: "+multi_id_vendor1_item1_count);
 Logger.log("Item2: "+multi_id_vendor1_item2_count);
```

Comment: I recommend you refactor to use a more maintainable format: `[ [vendorid1, count1, count2], [vendorid2, count1, count2], ... ]` To resolve your "so many if/elseifs" dilemma, programmatically construct an object that maps between vendor ids and their names (i.e. you get that information from somewhere, so you can programmatically construct it vs hard-coding it). E.g. `var converter = { id1: "that company's name", id2: "other company name", id3: "another name", ... }; var vendorName = converter[item_counts[i]]; if (!vendorName) continue;`

Comment: Thanks you! I modified my "counting" code to return a 2d array instead, like you suggested, and that made it much cleaner to iterate through. I did run into a small obstacle with the array.push() method though. Since each vendor has multiple entries on the report (one for each delivery), when counting and pushing to the array I ended up with multiple array elements for the same vendor. In the original code I avoided this by using indexOf() to check if the array already contained a vendor ID before pushing, but this didn't work on a 2d array. I'll ask how to handle that in another post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object literal that associates each vendor ID with a vendor name.  The name can be retrieved using the ID.

```
  var objMapVendorToName,vendor,vendorName;

  objMapVendorToName = {//Associate a vendor ID with a vendor name
    'vendor_id1':'vendor_name1',
    'vendor_id2':'vendor_name2',
    'vendor_id3':'vendor_name3'
  }

  for (i=0; i<item_counts.length; i=i+3) {

    vendor = item_counts[i];

    vendorName = objMapVendorToName[vendor];

  // vendor_name_col is an array of Vendor Names obtained from Google Sheets table 
  // using getRange().getValues(). Iterate through the list 
// of Vendor Names in the table. If a match is found to vendorName, 
// enter data from the array.
  for (j=0; j<vendor_name_col.length; j++) {

    if (vendor_name_col[j][0] == vendorName) {

    // this section will eventually be replaced with code that 
    // enters item1 and item2 counts in the columns next to Vendor 
    // Names in Google Sheets table using getRange.setValue().
    // Displays VendorID/Vendor Name, followed by item counts.
      Logger.log(“Counts for "+ item_counts[i]+"/"+vendor_name_col[j][0]);
      Logger.log("Item1: "+item_counts[i+1]);
      Logger.log("Item2: "+item_counts[i+2]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sandy! This looks like exactly what I needed. Objects and arrays are still very new (and a bit intimidating) to me, but I will figure it out. One thing I forgot to mention, sometimes a vendor will have multiple vendor IDs associated with it. I'm assuming this code will only work correctly if each vendor has a unique vendor ID?

Comment: @RussR it'll work for that case, where you have two ids for the same name. If you have 1 key value but multiple entries, then you need to change the data structure (lest the later entry overwrite the earlier entry)

Comment: @tehhowch, sorry, but I’m not sure I fully understand what you mean when you say I need to "change the data structure." Do you mean how I build the item_counts array or the way I write the data to the spreadsheet? I modified Sandy’s code a bit to make everything work (it's at the end of my original post), but I’m not sure it’s the best (or correct) way to handle this part of the task. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I came up with was add another condition in the if statement to check whether the Vendor Name from the vendor_name_col has multiple Vendor IDs associated with it (I created an array of Vendor Names that have multiple vendors IDs). If so, counts for this Vendor are not written to the sheet. Then, I added an else if statement which catches any multi-ID Vendor Names and sums their items counts. Once all loop iterations are complete, these counts are entered in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @russr if duplicates are a thing, then you need to change your map object from `{key: value}` to {key: `[ value1, ... ]}`. You also need to then change how you use the object (since `var val = myObj[key]` is now `[val1, ...]` instead of `value`

Comment: I see what you mean, I just need to assign unique values (e.g. vendor_name1, vendor_name1a, vendor_name1b, etc.) to the object keys (vendor IDs), which I can then identify and manipulate inside the code to get the correct item counts. Thank you! Do you see anything potentially wrong with the way I chose to handle duplicates?

Comment: @tehhowch Apologies, I don't think I understand. In my code object keys are Vendor IDs and values are Vendor Names. So Vendor Names get mapped to vendorName variable via Vendor IDs. vendorName is then compared to values in the vendor_name_col array (which contain vendor names from the spreadsheet). If there is a match between value in vendor_name_col and vendorName, then item counts for the Vendor ID associated with that Vendor Name are entered. In your example, `{key: [ value1, ... ]}` what would value1 be? Sorry if this is getting confusing.